# Can step-away structural tones have Neighbor tones?

Tags: melody, songwriting

As far as I understand, Neighbor tones(Upper and Lower tones) can only occur between repetition of structural tones as in the picture below.

[image]

but another picture suggests that between structure tones a step away can also have Neighbor tones.(diamond shaped notes are structural tones)

[image]

are both pictures right?

Answer (score 1):

The latter picture illustrates an "incomplete upper neighbor". There is also, of course, an "incomplete lower neighbor" for the inverse situation.

Incomplete neighbors are present in a variety of other ornamental structures. For example, when the incomplete neighbor is approached by leap and rhythmically accented it's an "appoggiatura". When the neighbor is approached by step but left by leap, it's an "escape tone".

**Appoggiatura**

[image: Appoggiatura]

**Escape tone**

[image: Escape tone]

Image source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonchord_tone)